# Get Audio path from document directory and convert in to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code and I get the URL path from directory, but did't convert into NSData.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER]];
NSData *Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:url];
```

Comment: What is `DOCUMENTS_FOLDER`? I guess it's most likely an invalid reference.

Comment: #define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]

Comment: Define Path on DOCUMENTS_FOLDER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSHomeDirectory()` appending `Documents` does not return the actual container directory in iOS.

You have to retrieve the URL – every time – from `NSFileManager`:

```
NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                             inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                    appropriateForURL:nil
                                                               create:NO
                                                                error:nil];
NSURL *cafURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.caf"];
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cafURL];
```

And it seems that the **file name** is missing in your code, too.